# How to compile BNF Converter?

Tags: haskell, ghc, bnf, ghci, alex

Did anyone succeed in building BNFC with ghc-7.2.1 and alex-3? I was trying to fix it manually, but there are lots of errors. Does anybody know where can I find some patches that will help me to get it done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've placed a modified darcs repo at http://www.tiresiaspress.us/haskell/bnfc/ .  It works with ghc-7.4 and alex-3 (I didn't change the docs, so it still says alex-2).  Very hackish, YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to build it (though I needed to modify BNFC.cabal, because it had mtl < 2 as a dependency and I've got 2.0.1.0 installed). I'll accept your answer as soon as I find out whether it works correctly :)

Comment: I didn't even try to build with mtl-2, but if it compiled it probably works.  I've only tried the haskell-generated stuff, so I've got no idea if the other outputs (java,yacc/bison,etc) are correct or not.